# Does the URL API require encodeURI for the pathname?

Tags: javascript

The [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) allows constructing URLs like this:

```
const url = new URL('/path', 'https://www.example.com')
```

But this will produce an invalid URL, because the percent sign is not encoded:

```
const url = new URL('/100%', 'https://www.example.com')
```

Does `URL` require using `encodeURI()` on the pathname (and the hash)?

(For the query parameteres, `URLSearchParams` *does* properly encode.)

Comment: Odd. It does encode some characters, E.g. space => %20 so presumably if you used encodeURI() you could get double escaping ...

Comment: Wrapping the args in `encodeURI` seems to work: `const url = new URL(encodeURI('/100 percent'), 'https://www.example.com')`. But as you say, it seems odd why this should be necessary.